# can not find symbol even with maven dependency

Tags: java, maven

Going nuts over this now. POM has the right dependency and the generated model from YAML has the proper `@JSONIgnoreProperties` annotation. I can even click on it to validate that its coming from right dependency. But at the end of the build, whether using Intelij Idea or terminal, there is a failure: `Can not find symbol JsonIgnoreProperties.`

Below is the screenshot of generated model, but after writing the file, build is failing in compilation phase.

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what "at the end of the build" means; please include the actual text output and the relevant portions of the pom and build config..

Comment: Can you try to remove the `fasterxml` dependency in your Maven cache and rebuild.  It'll be something like `~/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml`.  I'd remove the entire `fasterxml` directory and let Maven re-download.  It's uncommon but I've seen this happen once in a while.

Comment: And make sure that your IDEA uses the same maven (including the right .m2 folder) that you are modifying.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs everyone. Got a resolve to this. Added package name to the annotation in my openapi maven plugin config options and issue was fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the inputs everyone. Got a resolve to this. Added package name to the annotation in my openapi maven plugin config options and issue was fixed.